# Youtube content owner API returns 403 forbidden error

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

The API Explorer returns 403 forbidden with fetchMine=True https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/contentOwners/list
Used Google OAuth 2.0 and API key. Is it compulsory to be a a partner to gain access to the data?

Answer (score 2):

## directly from the documentation page.

[ContentOwners: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/docs/v1/contentOwners/list)

> Note: The YouTube Content ID API is intended for use by **YouTube content partners** and is **not** accessible to all developers or to all YouTube users. If you do not see the YouTube Content ID API as one of the services listed in the Google API Console, see the YouTube Help Center to learn more about the YouTube Partner Program.

## answer

you need to be a YouTube partner to access this method.